# Give reference from table data in one sheet to cell in other sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

This is table data which is the source in SHEET 1.
I want to fill the data in other sheet SHEET 2.

[image]

like i want to copy the **J** of **Cross** in that location from SHEET 1

I tried using DGET function but it returns #VALUE!

Help me here

Comment: VLOOKUP() or INDEX() with MATCH() , but search as there are many examples already on here. See this for one : https://stackoverflow.com/q/14987017/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in cell `G4` -

`=INDEX(Sheet1!A:K, MATCH(H4, Sheet1!$B:$B, 0), MATCH($G$2, Sheet1!$A$13:$K$13, 0))`

You can do the same for other cells.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Ahmed for understanding me. Got it